# Method Signature - Difference Between TestMethod<T>() and TestMethod(type t)

Tags: c#

What is the difference between the following two method signatures:

```
public static void test<T>()
```

vs

```
public static void test(Type t)
```

I know that the second one allows a type to be passed to the method but I am not clear on exactly what the first one is doing differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the former, your type *must* be known at compile time, and you will able to use "T" within the method as a stand-in for the name of the type for things like variable declarations or casting as if you were writing normal code.

With the latter the type might not be known until runtime, but you will have to use reflection or dynamic objects to accomplish certain things that would be much easier (and type-safe) with the generic.

Answer (score 2):

The first one requires the type (T) to be specified at compile time, and is a generic method.

The second one allows you to specify a type at runtime, and is a non-generic method.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a generic method. This means a number of things:

- The type is resolved at *compile time*. You can call `test<int>` or `test<String>`, but you cannot call `test<t>` with `t` being a variable.
- Since the type is resolved at compile time, you can use this type in other parts of the method, e.g. as the return type, as the type of a parameter or as the type of a variable inside the method. Example:

  ```
  public static T test<T>(T param) { ... }

  int x = test(myString);   // Causes a compile-time error
  ```